# How to select and print the specifc first word from file?

Tags: c

This code is reading the first word (e.g. first & the last name but considered as one word with the difference of comma) from each line but how can I select the specific one? *like* I just want print the `data[1]` or just want to print `data[0]`

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  char string[STRING_LEN];
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  char * data[2];
  char * line = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  while(fgets(string, STRING_LEN, fp1)){
    data[i] = strtok(string, ",");
    printf("data[%d] = %s\n", i, data[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**The result it is giving**

```
data[0] = Bilal Khan
data[1] = Ali Ahmed
data[2] = Michael Jackson
```

**Expected output**

```
data[1] = Ali Ahmed
```

Comment: Separate printing from reading? First read and parse the file. Then when it's finished print whatever data you want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I separate it but not working

Comment: Describe specifically what doesn't work.  Show actual input and output, and show how this differs from what you expect.  Your program as written has undefined behavior the moment you read more than 2 lines from the file.

Comment: @paddy the result is showing `data[0] = word1, data[1] = word2` but I want to select specific word and print it

Comment: You misunderstand me.  Do NOT add this to the comments.  Edit your question.  Do NOT describe the input and output in your own words.  Copy and paste the exact input and output and put it in your question.  Programming is about being precise.  You are being vague.  Your program, as currently written, will output all text that appears before the first comma for the first two lines of input, and then be completely unpredictable after that due to trashing the stack by overflowing the `data` array.

Comment: @paddy I have updated. The result is showing due to loop but I want to print specific one like just data[0] or data[1] or data[2]

Comment: There is no such thing as `data[2]`.  It does not exist.  Thanks for adding the _output_ to your question.  Now show the _input_.  STOP describing what you need in terms of code, because you are having difficulty explaining it.  Instead, show what output you want your program to have if it is working the way you want.  This is called "expected output", and is one of the things I have already asked for.

Comment: @paddy it is simple bro. I just want to print individually data[0] = Bilal Khan or just data[1] = Ali Ahmed or just data[2] = Michael Jackson. like `printf("%s\n", data[0])` or `printf("%s\n", data[1])` or `printf("%s\n", data[2])`

Comment: [Previous OPs post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312911/how-to-read-the-first-wordcomma-separated-of-each-line). Please post an [MCVE] - please post a sample of csv file. `how can I select the specific one?` "how" are usually broad question. Iterate over strings returned by strtok up until the one you are interested in.

Comment: It is simple bro: show actual input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: @paddy, I have updated. You can see this now.

Comment: Have you considered putting `if (i == 1)` in front of your printf?  And stop using `data` as an array, because you are running off the end of it.

Comment: @paddy, Thank you, bro, I got it. I used if-statement to get the specific result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Would you code this : ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200


int main(){
  char string[STRING_LEN];
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  char * data[2];
  char * line = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  while(fgets(string, STRING_LEN, fp1)){
    data[i] = strtok(string, ",");
    if (i == 0) // new stuff here you can replace 0 with what ever you want
        printf("data[%d] = %s\n", i, data[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or would you just display the First Name instead of First Nmae + Last Name ?